# Should I redirect Https to http in alb aws?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8.5, aws-application-load-balancer

So I have a load balancer connected to an ec2 instance. The ec2 has a php website running on port 8000 hosted in iis 8.5. Now http health check is passing after adding binding in iis for port 8000, but https health check is failing. But since in iis, I have used URL rewrite to redirect all http into https, thus even if load balancer's https health check is failing I can still access website on https connection.
But I really want to make my health check for https pass.
So for that I figured out, I either run https application inside ec2 on a different port than 8000 and add a binding for it (dropped the idea cause client didnot want) OR,
Redirect https target group to http target group.
Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question.  I'm not sure if this would be better suited for [webmasters.se] or [sf].

Comment: Usually, we using https between client and load balancer. Load balancer will check ssl. If connection is safe, request will forward to backend server through http. Otherwise shou unsafe message. So it is no necessary to use https between load balancer and backend server.